# Unit Test dependency to other frameworks / classes

Tags: unit-testing, abap

im currently getting more into Unit Testing but stumbled upon a problem regarding other frameworks / classes.
In the end of the tested method I call another framework which won't return any data but throws exceptions in case of an error. So in the current state it'd be impossible to get an "success" testcase.
So I'd either not have such a test case at all or do I create a private instance object which I redefine for testing never throwing an exception? Is there any easier/cleaner way to do that?

Currently I moved the call of the other class into a DAO method, but it also feels kinda weird to do it that way since its not a database access perse.

Comment: The goal of unit testing is to test only one method at a time, not external code. Your test must no depend on external code, hence the need of DAO (a Dependency generally speaking, and you do Dependency Injection to mock the dependency). You may use global interfaces and use `cl_abap_testdouble` to do DI. Anyway, you're good with DAO (test double would be a better term in your case).

Comment: @SandraRossi so if I'd expect different results from the external code I'd create a Test Double for that returning whatever I need. But in this case, where I just dont want it to throw an exception, I put it into the DAO? Always understood the DAO as more of an pure class keeping all data and database operations.

Comment: Just do what you need. I understand that you don't need a DAO, you need a test double. This test double will do nothing. Easy.

Comment: Are you aware of **Test Seams** that can be used for external dependencies? With Test seams, you can easily mimic the behaviour of external calls. 
 https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abentest_seams.htm  https://community.sap.com/t5/application-development-blog-posts/abap-test-seam-for-unit-test-with-external-dependencies-personal-guideline/ba-p/13357751

Answer (score 2):

For a good unit test, you need to isolate the unit from any other dependencies that might interfere with the results of the test. If a unit requires such a dependency to do anything meaningful, then that dependency needs to be mocked.

The database is one such dependency which needs to be mocked, and the class [`CL_OSQL_TEST_ENVIRONMENT`](https://help.sap.com/docs/abap-cloud/abap-development-tools-user-guide/abap-sql-test-double-framework) usually got you covered in this regard. So moving all database access to a DAL class and inject it everywhere might not actually be required.

But what about other dependencies?

In a perfect world, every unit would have all such external dependencies injected when it is created/called, and would receive them not as a `REF TO final_class` but as a `REF TO interface`, allowing you to just implement that interface with a trivial class that basically does nothing or with [the test double framework](https://community.sap.com/t5/application-development-blog-posts/abap-test-double-framework-an-introduction/ba-p/13305196). Unfortunately we live in an imperfect world where such an architecture isn't always feasible or even possible.

So what can we do in such a case?

- If the external dependency is a function module, those can be automatically mocked by a different one for the duration of the test [using the class `CL_FUNCTION_TEST_ENVIRONMENT`](https://community.sap.com/t5/application-development-blog-posts/abap-test-double-framework-an-introduction/ba-p/13305196).
- Permissions can be simulated with [`CL_AUNIT_AUTHORITY_CHECK`](https://help.sap.com/docs/abap-cloud/abap-development-tools-user-guide/managing-dependencies-on-abap-authority-checks-with-abap-unit)
- We can add [`TEST-SEAM`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abaptest-seam.htm)s to the code under test. That way we can either replace the initialization of the external dependency so it gets replaced with a test double, or dummy out the code that calls it. Yes, I know, test seams feel kind like cheating: Is it really a valid unit test when you changed the code while it was tested? But used responsibly they are an awesome tool to create meaningful unit tests without having to refactor your whole application.